# ng2-translate does not work with angular-cli build prod

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng2-translate

I added ng2-translate to my angular-cli project. 
It's work well in localhost but when I try to run it from ng build prod,
I got 404 not found:

http://MySite/assets/i18n/en.json Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

The file exist in this path, but not found by the browser.

I added this providerto app.module.ts:

providers: [
     { 
      provide: TranslateLoader,
      useFactory: (http: Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, 'assets/i18n', '.json'),
      deps: [Http]
    }]

Maybe I should have to add some declaration to angular-cli.json? but what?

Comment: angular 2 - final release

Comment: angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.15
node: 6.4.0
os: win32 x64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I found the solution. 
I need to add an .json file to IIS configuratin:

```
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
</staticContent>
```

Now the translation work well.